# refresh only this part of Data (Google Maps)

Tags: java, ajax, google-maps, jsp

I am using, **JPA**, **Servlets** and **JSP** for a **google map** project which i am working on.

The JPA entity is called **"Locations"**

**"Locations"** entity class has a constructor that takes :

```
public Locations(Double latitude,Double longitude,String name,int people)
{this.latitude = latitude; this.longitude=longitude,this.name=name, this.people=people}
```

I have a class called LocationData, whereby i return an ArrayList of all the Locations in the database alongside their `latitude,longitude,PeopleAvailableNow`  in a method called **getLocation** as such :

```
ArrayList locations = new ArrayList() ;

List<Location> locations = query.getResultList(); //This contains all the Locations

for (Location s : locations) {

locations.add(new Location(s.lat,s.lon,s.name,s.people))

}
return locations
```

In my **servlet**, i pass the list of Locations as such :

```
ArrayList list = ld.getLocations();
String json = new Gson().toJson(list);
response.setContentType("text/json");
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
response.getWriter().write(json);
```

**In my map.js which is used by JSP**

```
// get locations from server
$.getJSON("locations", {}, function(data){

$.each(data, function(index, element){

                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(element.lat, element.lng),
                    map: map,
                    title: element.name,
                    people : element.people,                    
                });
                markers.push(marker);
```

So now, having a clear view of how the program runs, all the markers appear on the map and i use info window to display the people and name of marker(location). The thing is, the number of people could always change in the database since a person can leave one location and go to another.

1. How could i always get the "people" value refreshed(read from entity) at certain intervals ?
2. Is my design incapable of accommodating this, how could i change it to suffice this ability ?

Comment: shouldn't be very hard to set a refresh timer to either reload the page or re-execute the getJSON call.  Depending on how often you allow it you could eat up a lot of resources for no differences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to make it work.

What i did was, i created a method in the LocationData java class that has an input parameter of the persons name, and based on that returns the attributes of that person.

Then i created a second servlet, this one only returns the value of the person and not all people like the latter does. I wrote in the `doGet` of the servlet

```
String personname = request.getParameter("personName"); //This will be received from an Ajax call
ArrayList list = ld.getLocation(personname);
String json = new Gson().toJson(list);
response.setContentType("text/json");
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
response.getWriter().write(json);
```

In the Javascript, i have an ajax called placed in the onbutton click of the marker that gets the data as such

```
$.ajax({
                            dataType: "json",
                            type: 'GET',
                            url: 'servleturl',
                            data: {"personName": marker.getTitle()},
                            success: function(response) {
                              //do stuff here to perform the unique action to the marker}

                       });
```

Answer (score 0):

The best is to use WebSocket and only refreshing when your backend data change.

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/websocket003.htm#BABGJEIG